# How to add/update the array department using the useState in react hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have a problem, I'm trying to add/update the data object after selecting an item.

here's the code:

```
const [roomDept, setDept] = useState([{ code: null, dept: null }]);
const [department, setDepartment] = useState([]);

const appendRoomDpt = () => {
  setRoomDept(array => [...array, { code: null, dept: null }]);
}
return (
  <div>
    <ButtonGroup>
      <IconButton icon={<Icon icon="plus" />} onClick={() => appendRoomDept()} />
    </ButtonGroup>
roomDept.map((item, index) => (
    <div key={index} className="flex">
      <div className="flex-1 pb-2">
        <SelectPicker
          placeholder={"Select Room"}
          data={room['data']}
          labelKey="name"
          valueKey="code"
          style={{ width: '120px' }}
          cleanable={false}
          disabledItemValues={roomDept.map(x => x.code)}
          onChange={(value) => {
            const id = room['data'].filter(x => x.code === value).map(x => x.id);
            (function getDepartment() {
              useDepartments.getAll({ room: id, length: 9999 }).then(response => {

                //Here's what I'm trying to do

                let dept = [...department];
                dept[index] = response['data']['data']
                setDepartment(department);
                console.log(department)

              });
            })()
          }}
          value={roomDept[index].code}
        />
      </div>

    </div>
    ))
  </div>
)
```

assuming `roomDept` I click the button add. then there's a two selection.
after that when I try to select on the first select field it will append on the department, but when I try to select on the second field it will just replace instead of adding. for example

I select on the first select field. the output is like this.

`[{code: 'r1', name: 'room 1'}]`

then when I try to select on the second select field the output just replace on it

`[{code: 'r2', name: 'room2'}]`

instead it will add, where it should be like this.

`[{code: 'r1', name: 'room 1'},{code: 'r2', name: 'room2'}]`

on the update side it should update base on the index and it will not add/append.

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle or a codesandbox?

Comment: @MannyAlvarado https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-roentgen-u9zjj

Answer (score 0):

Always remember these three lines to update a state that stores an array

Break object to create a new one.
Update that new object with the new value.
setState with that new object.

It goes like so:

```
let newObj = { ...state }
newObj.keyToBeUpdated = updatedArray
setState(newObj)
```

That's it.

Comment: its not an object its an array sir. https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-roentgen-u9zjj?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to essentially update the state, could you just concat the original state array with the new one on click? Something along the lines of:

```
const appendRoomDpt = (array) => {
    setRoomDept( [...roomDept,...array]);
  }
```